# PowerBI Workspace cannot access Azure Synapse SQL Serverless Views

Tags: powerbi, azure-synapse, powerbi-datasource

I am connecting to a SQL Serverless endpoint located in my Azure Synapse Account for my PowerBI Datasets. I am reading a SQL view that is composed of some parquet files in my data lake.

I am able to connect to the data fine when using PowerBI Desktop since it is using my Active Directory account. But now that I have the report published to a PowerBI Workspace online for other users in my organization I want to have it refresh the dataset daily without having to publish it myself.

Using the online refresh settings I am able to connect to SQL just fine using basic authentication (username/password) but it looks like when PowerBI renders the view it is also checking the credentials for the underlying datalake data which it does not have access to:

```
Microsoft SQL: Cannot find the CREDENTIAL 'https://mydatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/parquet/**', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. Could not use view or function 'dbo.MyView' because of binding errors.
```

What is the best way for me to give my PowerBI Workspace permissions to read this view (along with underlying datalake files)?

I'm also puzzled that in PowerBI Workspace I ***had*** options to schedule this data set but after a few failed attempts it now states:

```
You can't schedule refresh for this dataset because the following data sources currently don't support refresh:
```

And there is nothing after the ":" so now it appears I cannot attempt to connect anymore.

I have the PowerBI Workspace set as a linked service but that does not seem to help since I believe that is only for Synapse to use to connect to the workspace and not the other way.

I was toying with the idea of having Synapse copy the view data to a SQL database outside of Synapse so it can be shared more easily - but my preference would be to avoid this extra layer.

Comment: I have this same issue. were you able to figure it out?